# Grunt File Blocks `Required config property ... missing`

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I cannot seem to get fileblocks running. Every time I run grunt I get this error message:

```
Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "fileblocks:dev" (fileblocks) task
Verifying property fileblocks.dev exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "fileblocks.dev" missing. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I have a modular setup for integrating the various tasks executed by Grunt. I have installed file-blocks by running `npm install --save-dev grunt-file-blocks` and my `Gruntfile.js` is:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: require('./package.json')
  });

  grunt.loadTasks('grunt-tasks');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['wiredep', 'fileblocks:dev']);
};
```

Here's my `grunt-tasks/fileblocks.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    fileblocks: {
      dev: {
        src: 'app/*.html',
        blocks: {
          'css': {
            src: 'app/*.css'
          },
          'js': {
            src: 'src/*.js'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-file-blocks');
};
```

So, I expect `fileblock:dev` to run the fileblocks task `dev` that I've defined, but I get the aforementioned error. Help!

Comment: I think `grunt.loadTasks('grunt-tasks');` might load the tasks loaded by `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-file-blocks');`, but `grunt.loadTasks` function doesn't load the config. The config used by grunt when you try to execute 'default' task only contains what you specified in `grunt.initConfig()`in your Gruntfile.js. In your case, only the content of the package.json file. Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-modules, it might be what you need.

Comment: I don't agree, as my wiredep task is defined in the initConfig call in its own file in the same directory, it's just that it doesn't have this nested task definition. I'll try with grunt modules and see how that works.